# Any issues with always using ASP.NET MVC AsyncController instead of Controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

We have a series of ASP.NET MVC controllers that all inherit from a single base controller (that inherits from the Controller class).  We are now looking at creating some asynchronous actions, and was wondering if we'd run into any trouble if we just changed the base controller to inherit from AsyncController instead of Controller (meaning all of our controllers would inherit from AsyncController).

Comment: There is a really good blog post about asych controllers here http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/04/05/improve-scalability-in-aspnet-mvc-using-asynchronous-requests/

Comment: @Miau: That article looks pretty old; the author is rolling his own AsyncController class.

Comment: Use MVC 4 where  Controller supports asynchronous operations and there is no implemented Async controller class. See my MVC async tutorial and my answer below. http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jess,

In my opinion, you'll do no harm as the asynch functionality is only called into play when you follow the conventions of:

```
public class PortalController : AsyncController
{
    public void NewsAsync(string city)
    {

        AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Increment();
        NewsService newsService = new NewsService();
        newsService.GetHeadlinesCompleted += (sender, e) =>
        {
            AsyncManager.Parameters["headlines"] = e.Value;
            AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Decrement();
        };
        newsService.GetHeadlinesAsync(city);
    }

    public ActionResult NewsCompleted(string[] headlines)
    {
        return View("News", new ViewStringModel
        {
            NewsHeadlines = headlines
        });
    }
}
```

the convention being the addition of the News*Async* and the News*Completed* portions in the naming.

see:

[async controllers in asp.net mvc 2](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2010/03/29/asynchronous-controllers-in-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx)

*Observe that the controller class now derives from AsyncController rather than Controller. In addition, the News action method has been split into methods named NewsAsync and NewsCompleted, which are analagous to the Begin and End methods in asynchronous pages. Logically, the controller still exposes a single action method named News. But physically, the method implementation has been broken up using a variation on the async pattern used throughout the .NET framework.*

If you don't change anything in your inherited controller code, then no async activty will be initiated. However, as stated by Robert above (or below maybe :-)), you could decorate the actions on a needs must basis to keep the intention clear, tho', i personally think the convention should show that up clearly.

certainly worthy of debate.

Comment: Thanks jim - so am I correct in saying there are no concrete benefits to using Controller over AsyncController?

Comment: Jess - other than what Robert alluded to earlier (re clarity of purpose), then i'm of the opinion that you get more benefits by having the asynccontroller base. as we know, you don't 'have' to use the features. to be honest, i've been using it in my base controller for quite some time and only have one single instance of where it's used. but that single use is so clearly defined that it's no mystery as to what's going on elsewhere. in fact, as my inherited controllers only show MyController : BaseController, there's no real clue that i'm using the controller any differently to before...

Comment: Oh ! somehow AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Increment/Decrement is important, the async behaviour does not work without that. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/9805030/1182982

Answer (score 2):

MVC 4 doesn't have an asynch controller - see the source:

```
    namespace System.Web.Mvc
{
    // Controller now supports asynchronous operations.
    // This class only exists 
    // a) for backwards compat for callers that derive from it,
    // b) ActionMethodSelector can detect it to bind to ActionAsync/ActionCompleted patterns. 
    public abstract class AsyncController : Controller
    {
    }
}
```

See my tutorial [Using Asynchronous Methods in ASP.NET MVC 4](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-)

Answer (score 1):

You should be fine doing that since `AsyncController` already inherits from `Controller`.

[See here for more information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.asynccontroller%28VS.98%29.aspx)

The remarks on that page are quite useful for determining whether you're doing the right thing by inheriting from `AsyncController` and offers a nice guide to keep you on track.

Answer (score 1):

If you set a breakpoint in your Action method and observe the callstack (with Show External code enabled), you will see that there are several additional steps required to invoke a synchronous action residing in an AsyncController vs. in a standard Controller. Namely the AsyncControllerActionInvoker invokes Begin/End style methods ending with BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod.  I don't know how much overhead these extra calls contribute, but it is something to be aware of before you blindly extend all your controllers from AsyncController even where no Async actions exist.

Answer (score 0):

The use of an Async Controller depends on whether you want to wait for any particular task or step to complete before going on to the next task. The problem is akin to buying something from Amazon before the money from your paycheck hits your checking account.

For typical web applications, I would say this is not advisable.  The web server is already very parallel, so the only advantage would be speeding up responsiveness to the user.  For many operations this benefit would be negligible.

I would reserve the Async Controllers for long-running processes in the background, where it is impractical to wait for the task to complete before returning the web page back to the user's control.

**NOTE:** If you have a copy of a .NET disassembler (or the [ASP.NET MVC source](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets)), you can open up the AsyncController class and have a look at the code.  That should give you a pretty good idea whether or not you can use the `AsyncController` as an ordinary `Controller`.

The article I linked to below says this: *"Controllers that derive from AsyncController enable ASP.NET to process asynchronous requests, and they can still service synchronous action methods."*

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598.aspx

Comment: robert - i think the OP was referring to inheriting from the asynccontroller per se, rather than implementing all calls as asynch. i may be wrong tho' i was once before :)

Comment: @jim: Ah, I see. Inherit from AsyncController, then use it synchronously? Why not just use an ordinary controller and switch it to AsyncController if the need arises?  That would certainly be better from a "making your intent clear" standpoint.

Comment: robert, i think perhaps Jess may be intending to use some actions synchronously and others async. but i get your point re making the intention clear from the outset...

Comment: @jim: Reading the question again, it looks like this is about retaining some functionality in a custom base class. I don't know enough about the internals of `Controller` and `AsyncController` to know if Jess' strategy will work; in theory you ought to be able to inherit from AsyncController and use the functionality from Controller in the usual way (assuming no methods from Controller are shadowed in AsyncController).

Comment: robert - i'm reading it along the lines of 'if we change the base controller to async, will it cause issues in existing controllers that have inherited from it'. maybe the OP could clarify the nuances on that. _;). just saw the edit above. yes i agree 100% with that (i.e. in theory you ought to be able to inherit from AsyncController and use the functionality from Controller in the usual way)

Comment: @jim - you are interpreting my question correctly ... in essence - if the AsyncController is just a regular Controller with some additional features, why not just use AsyncController all the time (but handle 99% of all actions synchronously)?  I wanted to make sure there were not any drawbacks to doing so.